# Column not mapped properly in Android Room when joining multiple tables with colliding column names via a junction table

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

I have the following entity:

```kotlin
@Entity(tableName = "category",
        foreignKeys = [ForeignKey(entity = PlannableItemEntity::class,
                                  parentColumns = ["plannable_item_id"],
                                  childColumns = ["plannable_item_id"],
                                  onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE)],
        indices = [Index(value = ["plannable_item_id"], unique = true)])
data class CategoryEntity(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) @ColumnInfo(name = "category_id") var id: Long = 0L,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "plannable_item_id") var plannableItemID: Long,
    @ColumnInfo var name: String?) {

    fun toCategory(): Category {
        Log.d("CategoryEntity", "toCategory: $this")
        return Category(id, name!!)
    }

    companion object {
        fun fromCategory(category: Category): CategoryEntity? {
            val plannableItem = category.plannableItem
            if (plannableItem == null) {
                Log.w("CategoryEntity",
                      "Passed category has a null reference: plannableItem. Please, pass a full category.")
                return null
            }
            return CategoryEntity(id = category.id,
                                  plannableItemID = plannableItem.id,
                                  name = category.name)
        }
    }
}
```

When selecting this via

```kotlin
private const val SAF = "SELECT * FROM"

@Dao
interface CategoryDao : GenericInsertUpdateDeleteDao<CategoryEntity> {
    @Query("$SAF category")
    fun getAll(): Flow<List<CategoryEntity>>
// ... 
}
```

It works fine (I get everything from the DB as expected).

However, when I try to retrieve the table along with the related tables, by using this entity:

```kotlin
data class CategoryFullWithActivities(
    @Embedded val categoryEntity: CategoryEntity,
    @Relation(
        parentColumn = "plannable_item_id",
        entityColumn = "plannable_item_id"
    ) val plannableItemEntity: PlannableItemEntity,
    @Relation(
        parentColumn = "category_id",
        entityColumn = "activity_id",
        associateBy = Junction(ActivityCategoryCrossRef::class)
    ) val activityEntities: List<ActivityEntity>? = null
) {
    fun toCategory(): Category {
        Log.d("CatFullWActivities", "toCategory: $this")
        val category =  categoryEntity.toCategory()

        category.activities = activityEntities?.map { it.toActivity() }?.toMutableList()
        return category
    }
}
```

using this query:

```
    @Transaction
    @Query("""SELECT c.*, a.*, pi.*
        FROM category c
        JOIN plannable_item pi 
            ON pi.plannable_item_id = c.plannable_item_id
        LEFT JOIN activity_category_xref xref 
            ON xref.category_id = c.category_id 
        LEFT JOIN activity a 
            ON xref.activity_id = a.activity_id""")
    fun getAllCategoriesWithActivities(): Flow<List<CategoryFullWithActivities>>
```

The code compiles, BUT `categoryEntity.name` is filled as null.
The database contents look like this:

`category`:

| category_id | plannable_item_id | name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| -1 | 2 | Categ1 |
| -2 | 3 | Categ2 |

`plannable_item`:

| plannable_item_id |
| --- |
| 2 |
| 3 |

There are records in `activity`, BUT there is currently no record in the junction table `activity_category_xref`. This is a valid situation, and in this case, the `CategoryFullWithActivities.activityEntities` should just be null. But that's not the problem anyway - what happens is that in `CategoryFullWithActivities`, the `categoryEntity.name` is null every time.

It might be worth noting that `ActivityEntity` also contains a field `name`. Same with the table, eg. `activity.name`.

Still, is Room not able to figure it out? I thought of using prefixes, but apparently they are only supported when using `@Embedded`, and I couldn't make that work with a junction table.

Comment: The tables appear formatted correctly in the preview... I'll try to fix it. (EDIT: done)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Selecting each value explicitly and prefixing the joined tables seems to have worked (though I'm not 100% sure why):

```kotlin
    @Transaction
    @Query("""SELECT c.category_id, 
        c.name, 
        c.plannable_item_id,
        a.activity_id, 
        a.plannable_item_id AS activity_plannable_item_id, 
        a.name AS activity_name, 
        a.is_formally_tracked AS activity_is_formally_tracked, 
        a.default_measurement_type_id AS activity_default_measurement_type_id,
        pi.plannable_item_id
        FROM category c
        JOIN plannable_item pi 
            ON pi.plannable_item_id = c.plannable_item_id
        LEFT JOIN activity_category_xref xref 
            ON xref.category_id = c.category_id 
        LEFT JOIN activity a 
            ON xref.activity_id = a.activity_id""")
    fun getAllCategoriesWithActivities(): Flow<List<CategoryFullWithActivities>>
```

There might be issues with this down the road. I'll post updates if that happens.